# How to use the GPU on Jupiter Notebook?

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, gpu, windows-11

[image: screen shot on Jupyter notebook]

Hi, I want to use the GPU in a Jupyter notebook.

**Hardware**:

Windows 11 and GrForce GTX 1660 SUPER

I did,

1. installed the NVIDIA studio (531.61 - WHQL) driver
2. installed NVIDIA Toolkit-12.x
3. installed cuDNN 12
4. unzipped cuDNN, coppied and pasted **lib, include, bin** folders into CUDA in NVIDIA Toolkit
5. Added the path to the environment system variable
6. deleted the already installed tensorflow-2.12.1
7. reinstalled tensorflow 2.10.0
8. installed tensorflow-gpu 2.10

I Checked for GPU using `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))>0`, but GPU was not caught.

I also set `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"`, but it also did not work.

I'm wondering what else I can do here.

Do I need to version tensorflow-intel or other dependencies the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try again by creating new Virtual Environment and install tensorflow 2.10 and all the required software (Nvidia driver, CUDA, cuDNN) for GPU support.

Please install `CUDA 11.2` and `cuDNN 8.1` for the `tensorflow 2.10` as mentioned in this [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu).

You can refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) for installing tensorflow with GPU support. Let us know if the issue still persists.